# Google ads does not open in new tab by clicking on ad. How to fix it so that it could be open in new tab?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, adsense

I have created a Google ad and deploy it in my website. Any user/visitor when click on this ad it is opened in same tab instead of new tab. It must be open in new tab so that user/visitor could not lose website.

Sometimes ad is opened in same tab and sometimes ad is opened in new tab. What is happening there? I'm confused.

Is there any logic/selection to force ad to open in new tab during ad creation or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not allowed by google.

You can read more :

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354740?hl=en&ref_topic=1271508

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/TMSSYotv_Xw

Comment: But in some website ads open in new tabs. eg: http://www.spiegel.de/

Comment: Then whose ad service ?

Comment: But in some website ads open in new tabs example https://www.mathrubhumi.com/